# Create static graphics files (png, gif, jpg) using Ruby or Python

Tags: python, ruby, graphics, png

I'd like to create a graphic image on the fly based on user input, and then present that image as a PNG file (or jpg or gif if necessary, but PNG is preferred).

This is actually for an astrology application; what I'd like to do is generate the chart in PNG for display.

Python or Ruby is fine; in fact, the library available may determine the language I use.

#### Update

Here's an example image:
[image: Example horoscope graphic chart]

Comment: Similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704670/ruby-rails-image-processing-libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [Gruff](http://nubyonrails.com/pages/gruff) easy to use when I was in your shoes. 
[Shameless blog plug](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2008/12/graphs-in-ruby-on-rails.html).

Comment: Gruff link is dead.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe a vectorial format is better suited for your needs, but is hard to tell without having a concrete example of what you'd like to get.

For example, if the images are all alike, you could create a SVG base image with Inkscape, then edit it programmaticaly from Python or Ruby (either by editing the text or using a XML library) and finally export it to PNG.

---

**Update:**
After seeing the example image, I think SVG would be the most convenient choice.  A SVG image is an XML file that basically says "draw a circle from here to here, write the string '13º52' there", etc.  You could draw a unique base chart in Inkscape and have your program just adding the lines and symbols for each case.  Finally you export to PNG.

The advantages are: easier for you to draw, the image is fully scalable, you can change the styling just by editing a property ("make all lines wider", "change all text to Arial", "paint the background blue"), you can export to any format without losing quality, and I think it's more mantainable.

Comment: Graphic link is above. The thing about vector formats is I'm not sure how portable they are; I don't expect my target audience to be very technical.

Comment: Vector formats make it easier to draw, and you could deliver the final image exported as PNG to your users.

Answer (score 9):

In Python, you'd typically use PIL, the Python Image Library. I've never used PIL for anything beyond the simplest tasks, so I can't say how well it performs in practice.

I'd start digging into PIL with a look at [its documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/), particularly the [documentation for the draw module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm).

Comment: +1: did it last week.  Worked nicely -- creates on-the-fly charts.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Ruby-GD2](https://github.com/jojje/gd2-ruby) or an ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick binding.

Answer (score 2):

For Python I the most common choice for image formats is PIL and then [Pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) for vector formats.  The two can work together, for exadmple in this cookbook entry to [use PIL images for Pycairo surfaces](http://cairographics.org/pythoncairopil/).

Answer (score 1):

when I was doing python chalange (http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) I've used Python Image Library (http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/)