# Rails / Ruby - What gem can create a image with text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Example I have a image.

[image]

In my controller I example have `@name = "Jon"`

Now I want to create a new image as the image I got just with the name "Jon" in the middle of the image. I want to be able to specify the font-size, color and font-family that should be used and the position of the text.

[image]

What gem are able to do that?

Comment: Think I will use imagemagick - It's just a pain to install :(

Comment: Imagemagick via Rmagick is probably the (only?) way to go. Yea installing it all properly is usually a pain but c'est la vie.

Comment: Here is the same question with an answer a template:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704670/ruby-rails-image-processing-libraries][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704670/ruby-rails-image-processing-libraries

Comment: This Rmagick page might give you some good ideas ... http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/portfolio3.html

Comment: i want to do the same without rmagick :(

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png

Answer (score 13):

A basic rmagick solution isn't that bad, 6 lines. The following gives you a yellow rectangle with TEXT in the center. You can experiment with the font and point size. The center call is there because I thought it looked better in the middle.

```
require 'RMagick'

canvas = Magick::Image.new(300, 100){self.background_color = 'yellow'}
gc = Magick::Draw.new
gc.pointsize(50)
gc.text(30,70, "TEXT".center(14))

gc.draw(canvas)
canvas.write('tst.png')
```

I get the requirement, you can also go through. This should help.

Comment: @lulalala I've updated the solution have a look at it.

Comment: It appears trying to implement this snippet, with a basic install of imagemagick (via brew) and rmagic gem on mac, causes a font error: `unable to read font (null)`